# Enable autocompletion for all HTML input fields

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

On many websites autocompletion is disabled. Using my private PC which only I can access, I'd like the browser to store username and password anyways.

So I figured I could use the JS console and enter:

```
for (var f=0; f<document.forms.length; f++) {
  var els = document.forms[f].elements;
  for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
      //console.log(i + " " + els[i].value + " " + els[i].getAttribute("autocomplete"));
      els[i].setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
  }
}
```

However, testing on http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/html/autocomplete/beispiel1.htm it does not have the desired effect. What's wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not have the desired effect"? Did you try one of the "Autocomplete On" plugins for your browser?

Comment: The desired effect would be that the password entered in the second input mask of the example would be saved and loaded next time I use open the page (both after executing the JS code from above).

Comment: Just a wild guess: Maybe restoring the values only happens once during page load. So what you would need to do is tell the browser "restore values again, please". No idea how to do that, though.

Comment: It turned out that the JS code is good, but the sample page bad. My browser (Chrome) does only ask whether to save the password after the page with the password mask was left (the sample page just calls itself again after submitting username and password). It tried the code on the page of my bank, it works.